# converting HttpWebRequest from Synchronous to Asynchronous code

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I need to convert this code from sync to async code but every attempt so far has been dismal. Would anyone have a solution?

```
 var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Connection.GetUri(path).Uri);
 http.Accept = "application/json";
 http.ContentType = "application/json";
 http.Method = "POST";

 var parsedContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
 var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
 var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(parsedContent);

 var newStream = http.GetRequestStream();
 newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
 newStream.Close();

 var response = http.GetResponse();

 var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

 var sr = new StreamReader(stream);

 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TReturnType>(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

for context, the problem is that i cannot use the System.Net.Http assembly but need Async support
.
The above code has been ported from the following due to disability to use the above mentioned assembly. Connection.Client is type HttpClient.

```
var response = await Connection.Client.PostAsync(
   Connection.GetUri("/transaction/announce").Uri,
   new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Rpa).ToString(),
       Encoding.UTF8,
       "application/json"));

return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NemAnnounceResponse.Response>(
    await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Comment: Why can't you use `HttpClient`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpWebRequest` doesn't provide modern task-based asynchronous way to get response. But it allows you to make asynchronous call using old APM pattern. See [BeginGetResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Fortunately you can easily convert old-fashioned APM to task-based using helper methods like `Task.Factory.FromAsync`. Eventually you should get smth like this:

```
public static Task<WebResponse> GetResponseAsync()
{
    var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Connection.GetUri(path).Uri);
    http.Accept = "application/json";
    http.ContentType = "application/json";
    http.Method = "POST";

    var parsedContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(parsedContent);

    var newStream = http.GetRequestStream();
    newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    newStream.Close();

    Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
        http.BeginGetResponse,
        asyncResult => http.EndGetResponse(asyncResult),
        (object)null);

    return task;
}
```

And even call it using await like `var response = await GetResponseAsync();` and then proceed with response.